# Block directory but allow subdirectory in nginx

Tags: nginx

How can I block a parent directory but allow the sub directory in nginx?
I want something like this:

```
BLOCK
/dir1
/dir1/
/dir1/{any folder}

ALLOW
/dir1/dirA/dir2
```

```
location ~ ^/dir1/.+/(?!dir2)$ {
    return 403;
}
```

dir2 returns a 403 when I want a 200. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
location /dir1 {
    return 403;
}
location /dir1/dirA/dir2 {
    # some additional config could be added here if needed
}
```